# Scrolling problem using BBport

Tags: blackberry, java-me, lwuit

Scrolling fails on the BB Touch devices. As I scroll the container, the framework LWUIT BBport never detects the "release" and when I remove my finger from the device. As a result, the next press on the screen jumps me back to where the first scroll started.Can anyone faced the same problem and have fixed it please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 1.5? Torch broke compatibility with previous RIM devices and is only supported by the latest LWUIT release.

Comment: Thanks Shai for fixing the issue in the latest LWUIT n the scroll now works very fine.